# Extracting columns from Data Frame based on a "formula"

Tags: r

I have some data which looks like:

```
  data(iris)

  iris %>%
    select(Species, everything()) %>%
    rename(Y = 1) %>%
    rename_at(vars(-c(1)), ~str_c("X", seq_along(.)))
```

Data:

```
       Y  X1  X2  X3  X4
1 setosa 5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2
2 setosa 4.9 3.0 1.4 0.2
3 setosa 4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2
4 setosa 4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2
5 setosa 5.0 3.6 1.4 0.2
6 setosa 5.4 3.9 1.7 0.4
```

I add a random variable:

```
  d$noise <- rnorm(length(d))
```

I am trying to extract just the `Y, X1, X2... XN` variables (dynamically). What I currently have is:

```
d %>%
  select("Y", cat(paste0("X", seq_along(2:ncol(.)), collapse = ", ")))
```

This doesn't work since it takes into account the `noise` column and doesn't work even without the `noise` column.

So I am trying to create a new data frame which just extracts the `Y, X1, X2...XN` columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dplyr provides two [select helper functions](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.5.0/topics/select_helpers) that you could use --- `contains` for literal strings or `matches` for regular expressions.

In this case you could do

```
d %>%
  select("Y", contains("X"))
```

or

```
d %>%
  select("Y", matches("X\\d+"))
```

The first one works in the example you provided but would fail if you have other variables that contain any "X" character. The second is more robust in that it will only capture variables whose names are "X" followed by one or more digits.

Answer (score 1):

we can also use

```
d %>%
  select(Y, starts_with('X'))
```